# Scraping data and put it as array variable in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I found this tool with source code

demo:

```
http://googlesuggest-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html
```

source:

```
http://googlesuggest-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

the demo suggests related keywords and functions exactly like in Google search box auto-suggest features.

```
<script>
$.each("web youtube recipe products news images books".split(" "), function(i, v){
  var div = $("<div>").appendTo("#inputs")
    , input = $("<input>").appendTo(div)
    , span = $("<label>").text(v).appendTo(div);
  input.googleSuggest({ service: v });
});
</script>
```

based on the code above, how can I scrape the suggested data and save it as an `array` so that I can display it as a list.

Comment: Isn't it `function(v, i)` instead? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the source :)

The plugin is very simple apparently: [Source Code](http://googlesuggest-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.googleSuggest.js)

It makes an ajax call and process the return data to put them into `span` (it's using the standard autocomplete from jQuery UI it seems). The bit you need in the source code is here:

```
success: function(data) {
  response($.map(data[1], function(item){
    return { value: $("<span>").html(item[0]).text() };
  }));
}
```

Just do whatever you need there (preferably above the `response(...)` part to maintain functionality).